# Subtract one Pandas Series from another without creating NaN values for missing data

Tags: python, pandas, series, missing-data

When you subtract one series from another, the result contains NaNs if there is no record in the second series to subtract.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: a = pd.Series({1: 100, 2: 102, 3: 103, 4: 104})

In [3]: a
Out[3]:
1    100
2    102
3    103
4    104
dtype: int64

In [4]: b = pd.Series({1: 5, 3: 7})

In [5]: a - b
Out[5]:
1    95.0
2     NaN
3    96.0
4     NaN
dtype: float64
```

Is there an easier way to do the subtraction with the assumption that missing data is equivalent to zero?  Other than by manually inserting zeros like this:

```
In [15]: b_dash = pd.Series(b, index=a.index).fillna(0.0)

In [16]: a - b_dash
Out[16]:
1     95.0
2    102.0
3     96.0
4    104.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `sub`

```
a.sub(b,fill_value=0)
Out[213]: 
1     95.0
2    102.0
3     96.0
4    104.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can perform the subtraction and then `fillna` with your base Series (in this case `a`):

```
(a-b).fillna(a)

# 1     95.0
# 2    102.0
# 3     96.0
# 4    104.0
```

Or, you can use [`pd.Series.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html) (which will modify `a` in-place where there's a match with the indexes from `a-b`):

```
a.update(a-b)

# 1     95
# 2    102
# 3     96
# 4    104
```